# SQL recoverable Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, sqlexception

I am getting this stack trace on one of my test server.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection timed out
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.createTemporaryClob(T4CConnection.java:3401)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createClob(PhysicalConnection.java:9680)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.JDBCConnectionProxyFactory.invoke(JDBCConnectionProxyFactory.java:213)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.createClob(Unknown Source)
            at com.ril.payment.PaymentProxyDAO.initiateTransaction(PaymentProxyDAO.java:37)
            at com.ril.payment.PaymentProxyFIS.recharge(PaymentProxyFIS.java:153)
            at com.ril.payment.PaymentProxyService.recharge(PaymentProxyService.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

We are using Oracle 11g, Java 6 and plain JDBC.
Can give more information if required.

EDIT: 
A Requested

```
        poolDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(connectioPoolClass);
        poolDataSource.setURL(hostUrl);
        poolDataSource.setUser(userName);
        poolDataSource.setPassword(passwd);
        poolDataSource.setConnectionPoolName(UCP_POOL);
        poolDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(50);
        poolDataSource.setMinPoolSize(20);
        poolDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(200);
        poolDataSource.setConnectionWaitTimeout(5);
```

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: What all configuration setup you did for your connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html):

> The subclass of SQLException thrown in situations where a previously
>   failed operation might be able to succeed if the application performs
>   some recovery steps and retries the entire transaction or in the case
>   of a distributed transaction, the transaction branch. At a minimum,
>   the recovery operation must include closing the current connection and
>   getting a new connection.

In your case, a timeout means you should be able to recover from this by trying to connect again.

Of course you might have the exception every time if your connection is not setup properly and thus you are trying to connect to something tht isn't properly listening.